# Convert row into columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, table-of-contents

I have problem of converting column into rows for Fiscal_Q

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Edit/Paste Special ... Transpose

Comment: Do you mean a dynamic matrix convertion? Fox example: Convert Collumn A to row 1?

Comment: Edit your post and reload the Screen Shot,, since current one is not viewable (unable to open the link),, help us to analyze the data to fix the issue!!

Comment: You have Year Quarter data in column and the expected output shows pulled into Row but how you are getting other data shown below, are not to the left of Pivot Table,,!!